# Classification losses for binary classification

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, variational-bayes

I'm trying to classify a binary variable using a neural network.
I'm currently using CrossEntropyLoss as my criterion, but I don't really like it and was wondering what other options are available.

The reason I don't CE is that the data available for input is very limited and I don't think it is possible to properly classify the output with any certainty. CE decreases very slowly at the start and I think it prevents my model from learning properly.

What I mean by slowly:

- If the model always predicts 50/50 the loss would be 0.693 (-ln(0.5)).
- If the model predicts with accuracy/score of 60% the loss would be 0.673 (-(0.6*ln(0.6)+0.4*ln(0.4))), which is a very small decrease given huge increase in performance.

I was thinking about representing the target as a probability and using KL-divergence, but I don't have true probabilities and not sure about how to approximate them.

What other losses are there?

Comment: "which is a very small decrease  given huge increase in performance".  Why do you feel that way, and why does it matter really? The point of the loss function is that it is a function to be minimized. You could multiply your loss function by `10^4` if you'd like, and it would lead to the same model fitting procedure, but magnify all the differences. I'm not sure what the root of your issue here is.

Comment: @MatthewDrury It's small relative to other points on the curve: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/umijddklk7. Change from 0.7 to 0.8 is 0.11.

So if the model can improve some part of the dataset from 0.7 to 0.8 by decreasing performance on another part from 0.6 to 0.5, it would do that. But for my particular goal, these two changes in performance are equivalent.

In fact I'm probably more interested in moving away from random (0.5), than from improving further performance.